UIViewControllerRepresentable Unit test giving Context error
I am trying to add coverage for UIViewControllerRepresentable in my app but when I write unit test cases it gives below error:
UIViewControllerRepresentableContext cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
Here is the code
struct DocumentPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    var parent: DocumentPicker

    init(parent: DocumentPicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        parent.didPickDocuments(urls)
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        parent.didCancel()
    }
}

var didPickDocuments: ([URL]) -> Void
var didCancel: () -> Void

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(parent: self)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentPickerViewController {
    let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.item], asCopy: true)
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    picker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    return picker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIDocumentPickerViewController, context: Context) {} }

Here is the unit test cases:
class DocumentPickerCreationTests: XCTestCase {

func testMakeCoordinator() {
    let documentPicker = DocumentPicker(didPickDocuments: { _ in }, didCancel: { })
    let coordinator = documentPicker.makeCoordinator()
    XCTAssertNotNil(coordinator)
    XCTAssertTrue(coordinator is DocumentPicker.Coordinator)
}

func testMakeUIViewController() {
    let documentPicker = DocumentPicker(didPickDocuments: { _ in }, didCancel: { })
    let context = UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<DocumentPicker>(coordinator: documentPicker.makeCoordinator())
    let viewController = documentPicker.makeUIViewController(context: context)
    XCTAssertTrue(viewController is UIDocumentPickerViewController)
    XCTAssertEqual(viewController.delegate as? DocumentPicker.Coordinator, context.coordinator)
    XCTAssertTrue(viewController.allowsMultipleSelection)
} }


That representable isn’t right you can’t use self in Coordinator init cause it’s a value not an object. And you forgot to implement update which is the most important func.


Your code is not supposed to create UIViewControllerRepresentableContexts, or call makeUIViewController. You should let SwiftUI do that.
Most of the things you are testing, are trivial enough that doesn't need to be tested. Especially the is type checks, which are already enforced at compile-time.
Not everything should have a test written for it, and I hope this is not your real code. You should also consider writing UI tests, instead of working with your View types directly.

That said, if you want to find a UIViewController subclass out of a SwiftUI hierarchy, and do tests on that UIViewController, you can use View Inspector.
@MainActor
func testExample() async throws {
    let documentPicker = DocumentPicker(didPickDocuments: { _ in }, didCancel: { })
    ViewHosting.host(view: documentPicker)
    defer { ViewHosting.expel() }

    try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(100))

    let viewController = try documentPicker.viewController()
    XCTAssertTrue(viewController.delegate is DocumentPicker.Coordinator)
    XCTAssertTrue(viewController.allowsMultipleSelection)
}

Here, ViewHosting.host(view: documentPicker) adds the SwiftUI view into a view hierarchy, so that SwiftUI will call makeUIViewController and such. We need to wait for a moment because SwiftUI doesn't do that synchronously.

Is there any way to work without View Inspector library? @Sweeper

@ViralShah why don’t you want to use it? Sure you can write your own ViewHosting-like thing, but now you need to test that code. You end up having to test your tests, and I’d think that’s not a particularly good situation to be in. In fact, my advice is to not test the UIViewControllerRepresentable, which doesn’t have any business logic. You should test the view controller that this is wrapping, assuming it’s not UIDocumentPickerController.
